# Javascript: Selecting List from UL

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("parent-list");
document.querySelectorAll("#parent-list li").onclick = function() {

  alert('click!');

}
```

```html
<ul id="parent-list">
  <li id="item-1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item-2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="item-3">Item 3</li>
  <li id="item-4">Item 4</li>
  <li id="item-5">Item 5</li>
  <li id="item-6">Item 6</li>
  <li id="item-7">Item 7</li>
  <li id="item-8">Item 8</li>
  <li id="item-9">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to have an alert popup of the item clicked when I click on a "li" element with javascript only.  I know how to do in jquery but I can't figure out how to do it with javascript.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jcksznz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns an HTML collection. You would need to attach the event to each one. You would need to loop over the collection.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#test li");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="test">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

A better option is to add one click on the UL and use the event to determine which li was clicked.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var li = event.target;
  console.log(li.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ul id="test">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#parent-list li") get a collection of HTMLElement,so,you can do like this：
window.onload = function()
    {
        var ul = document.getElementById("parent-list");

        ul.onclick = function(e)
        {
            if(e.target.tagName = "LI")
            {
                alert(1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectAll returns array of nodes.
you have to iterate over the nodes to add the event listner.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("parent-list");
var li_items = document.querySelectorAll("#parent-list li");
for (var i = 0 ; i < li_items.length ; i++)
    li_items[i].onclick = function (){alert(this.id);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an event-listener targeted on each element rather than directly assigning an onclick function to a NamedNodeMap.

```
/* get an array of list items */
var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('li[id|="item"]')
);

/* add event-listener to each item */
items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', clickAlert, false);
});

/* click function */
function clickAlert(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id +' clicked!');
}
```

***See***:

- [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [eventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)